# gcc thunk hack for multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, gcc, multiple-inheritance

I have a class X having derived from Y and Z (interface). An object of this class is passed to a library as void* which has access only to interface Z. [ The reason its not passed as Z* is there is an intermediate component that only accepts void*]

The layout of the the vtable with gcc thunks would be X, Y point to same address, however Z points to X + 8

So, i need to typecast the object as (Z *) (obj + 8) to get to Z. Is this safe, are there alternatives? I cant use RTTI.

Comment: static_cast<Z*>(reinterpret_cast<X*>(obj)) where obj is a void*

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your design. If the end-of-chain function expects to get void* that is to be always casted to Z* then I would just modify the first-in-chain function to take Z* instead of void* (and then it case internally pass it further as void*). This way you get clean interface and compiler does all the dirty work.

Answer (score 3):

In this cases, just cast explicitly to the type you want to send with `static_cast`. It will take care of the details, as long as it knows both the type from/to it is converting.

That is:

```
X *theX = ...;
void *ptr = static_cast<Z*>(theX)
```

Then in the receiving code:

```
void *ptr = ...;
Z *theZ = static_cast<Z*>(ptr);
```

And if you *know* that it is actually an `X`:

```
X *theX = static_cast<X*>(theZ);
```

The bottom line is: whenever you cast a pointer into to `void*` and back, it should be converted to the very same type it was before.

Thus, this is undefined:

```
X *theX = ...;
void *ptr = static_cast<void*>(theX);
Z *theZ = static_cast<Z*>(ptr); //Undefined behavior!!!
```

Event though `Z` is a subclass of `X`, and a direct `static_cast` between the two would have worked.

Answer (score 2):

No, casting `(Z*)(obj + 8)` is not safe.

Cast the object to `Z*` before casting to `void*`, then cast the `void*` back to `Z*`. That will be safe.